# "A fatal Javascript error has occured. Would you like to send an error report?"

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am unable to access **phpMyAdmin** area because whenever I click on Databases tab, it generates this error:

> "A fatal Javascript error has occured. Would you like to send an error report?"

I am using latest Chrome browser and I have couple of extensions installed, namely: **Adblock Plus**, **Ruler**, **PageXray**, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also faced exact issue last week when I tried creating a new Database on my localhost after installing an extension named PageXray. Seeing that you also have PageXray extension installed, my solution would work for you.
There are two options to resolve this issue:

1. Remove this extension: PageXray and your localhost phpMyAdmin will work normally
2. If you wish to keep using PageXray then read below to make a change in the extension setting to bypass this error:

   - Right click on the PageXray icon which would be placed on address bar of Chrome (as seen in screenshot1)
   - Hover over "This can read and change site data" dropdown and select the option "When you click the extension"
   - Now you will be able to access phpmyadmin and other features without any problem.

Screenshot 1:
[image: Screenshot: set PageXray extension option to remove the error on phpmyadmin panel]

Now you will need to click PageXray extension icon every time you want to check the technology stack being used on the website.

Please let me know in case of any query and I will be happy to help more. Cheers!